# How to count related table records using Doctrine2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I'm quite new to doctrine, And i want to carry out a certain task.

I have `jobs` table with `category_id` column, And obviously `categories` table.

In Symfony2, I have this repository

```
<?php

namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getWithAllJobs()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->select('c, j')
                    ->leftJoin('c.jobs', 'j');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

Now when i get the result of `getWithAllJobs` function, It returns all categories even if it have no jobs related.

I want to only return the categories with related jobs. I'm thinking of counting `c.jobs` and select categories with `c.jobs` more than 0 or something. How to do that in doctrine ?

And if there's a better way, What is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only right way to do what you want is using `inner join` instead of `left join`. Your code should look like this:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->select('c, j')
                ->innerJoin('c.jobs', 'j');
```